# Symfony: get parameter names from URL string

Tags: php, symfony, url

Given a URL string like:

```
'my-route/{someId}/{someOption}'
```

I'd like to get an array like:

```
['someId', 'someOption']
```

Obviously I can parse it manually with some regexp, but I was wondering if it'd be possible to do it using some Symfony (2.6+) component or something...

So from wherever in my code I can do something like:

```
$urlParamNames = $someComponent->getParamNamesFromUrl('my-route/{someId}/{someOption}');
```

---

NOTE: I know this is not "standard" Symfony, and I know you'll normally get the parameters from the route injected into the action as arguments and so on... Explaining why I want this would be a very long story though, so just assume I need *exactly* that functionality, no other advices/suggestions...

Comment: first, symfony injects them as parameters into your action method. just define `$someId` and `$someOption` as parameters. second, you should be able to extract the parameters with the routing service

Comment: @Joshua I know :) See the note I added...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a strange request. But if you really want:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$compiledRoute = RouteCompiler::compile(new Route('my-route/{someId}/{someOption}'));
var_dump($compiledRoute->getVariables());
```

Output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "someId" [1]=> string(10) "someOption" }
```

Without using `RouteCompiler` directly:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$route = new Route('my-route/{someId}/{someOption}');
$compiledRoute = $route->compile();
var_dump($compiledRoute->getVariables());
```

See [`compiler_class`](https://github.com/symfony/routing/blob/master/Route.php#L283) option if you need to do more.